# -F parameter not working as I assume in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on my .htaccess right now, and obviously I ran into some trouble...
I've read tons of articles and docs and I still am not able to figure out what the problem is:

- I am trying to redirect the the user to an other public folder, if the user is accessing a sub domain
- If the user is accessing the top level domain he should be redirected into the main public folder
- If files don't exist in the folders redirect the user to index.php

This is what I came up with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond __/%2/public/$1 -F
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ __/%2/public/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond public/$1 -F
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond __/%2/public/$1 !-F
RewriteCond public/$1 !-F
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Sadly it is not really working... Well except if I comment out the last `RewriteRule`.

Any advice? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One problem is that your first condition's regex will also match `www.example.com` which is main domain not the sub domain.
2. `-f` requires full path not with relative paths so add `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/` in front of your path.
3. Use `-f` instead of `-F`
4. Last rule has no back-reference of `%2`

You can use following code in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?((?!www\.)[a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/__/%1/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ __/%1/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It's very weird... your code is not working either... it seems that my [L] flag is not working properly... the last RewriteRule is still being executed, even the file exists etc

Comment: I am trying no sub domaine: example.com/favicon.png or with sub domain: subd.example.com/favicon.png

Comment: If i add 'RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?((?!www\.)[a-z0-9-]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]' to the last RewriteRule then subd.example.com/favicon.png is working

Comment: No, i am just stating that even if the file exists all requests are being redirected to index.php?request=